# protected languages -> Redirection

Tags: security, login

I have requirement i.e. I have some protected languages like de-DE (German), when user browsing these language ex: http://www.xyz.com/de-DE then he must redirect to login page.

Could you please let me know where to which is best pipeline to add this code. I am trying to add the code using `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderLayout.SecurityCheck`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the language as soon as possible - so I would do it in the HTTPRequestBegin pipeline at the languageResolver.

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver, Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

This is depending on what action your site should take, offcourse. But it sounds like, it should change to a different language.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a different website for the German language (targeting the same content tree of course) then you can secure it easily through configuration and let Sitecore worry about anything further.

Comment: What if that same site is working in EN since then user can type the language code in URL and view the secured content of other Language?

Comment: Yes, if the currently authenticated visitor has access to content for that particular language. You can secure an entire language for different needs, read: roles & users

Comment: What about Anonymous users?

Comment: If the website is configured so that anonymous users cannot access either the site of the language then they will get the required login screen.